# Webpack install throws an error UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY webpack@4.6.0 invalid

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babel-loader

I am trying to compile an old project. `npm install -D webpack` earlier complained of webpack-cli install issue. Now if I try with the latest one `npm i -D webpack@4.6.0`, it is giving following error.

> └── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY webpack@4.6.0 invalid

```
npm WARN babel-loader@6.4.1 requires a peer of webpack@1 || 2 || ^2.1.0-beta || ^2.2.0-rc but none was installed.  
npm WARN webpack-dev-middleware@1.12.2 requires a peer of webpack@^1.0.0 || ^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 but none was installed.  
npm WARN webpack-dev-server@1.16.5 requires a peer of webpack@>=1.3.0 <3 but none was installed.  
npm WARN react-tutorials@0.0.0 No repository field.  
npm ERR! code 1
```

Comment: What are your `npm` and `node` versions?

Comment: npm - 3.10.8, node-v6.9.1

Comment: Update them. They are quite outdated.

Comment: I upgraded the versions but still.npm WARN webpack-cli@2.0.15 requires a peer of webpack@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself. I try that install webpack-cli with webpack command . It says Cannot find module 'webpack-cli' "process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:178:7) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }"

Comment: You need to install `webpack v4`. Do take note that this is a major change and your code is expected to break.

Comment: Keep in mind that nodejs's minimal supported version is `6.11.5` (for webpack 4). Specified in [package.json `engine`](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/package.json)

Comment: @eldarg I have already updated to node v10.0.0

Comment: @RuChernChong I had done npm i -D webpack@4.6.0, after that when I run 'webpack'. I receive the following message
The CLI moved into a separate package: webpack-cli
Would you like to install webpack-cli? (That will run npm install -D webpack-cli) (yes/NO) yes.    But then I receive error Cannot find module 'webpack-cli'. I am not sure what the problem is?

Comment: Looking at the logs, babel-loader, webpack-dev-middleware and webpack-dev-server has a peer dependency of webpack 1 or webpack 2. As you have webpack 4 installed it's considered the wrong version. Try to install webpack 2 to build the project (as @RuChernChong mentioned above it has many breaking changes and almost certainly break)

Comment: @eldarg Tried that also but all in vain

Comment: @Amit delete your `node_modules` folder and reinstall

Comment: I tried installing webpack@2.2.0. All dependencies are gone but only one remains in npm list i.e. npm ERR! peer dep missing: webpack@^4.0.0, required by webpack-cli@2.0.15. It requires 4.0.0. I am not sure how to resolve this interdepency. If I install 4.0.0, it shows the error I told you earlier